# jquery adding in select list by textbox

Tags: jquery

ok what i am trying to do is to add something in the textbox and after pressing the add button it should go into the select list. how would i do that with jquery?

I am not really able to make it work by your method .Please help? What i am doing wrong

<%= Html.ListBox("FeatureLists", ViewData["FeatureListListBox"] as MultiSelectList)%>

$("#add").click(function() {

       var val = $("#txtaddfeature").val();

        alert("aaa");
       $("", { 'value': val, text: val }).appendTo("#FeatureLists");
       //$("#textbox").val(''); here if you want to clear the value for next time
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), create the `<option>` using [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) and append it to the `<select>` using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
  var val = $("#textbox").val();
  $("<option />", { 'value': val, text: val }).appendTo("#selectList");
  //$("#textbox").val(''); here if you want to clear the value for next time
});
```